# Which celebrity's name is hidden in the above letters?

Tags: anagram

> D,X,F,L,H,A,T,E,E

**Which celebrity's name is hidden in the above letters?**

Hint 1:

> It's neither last name nor middle name.

Hint 2:

> It ranges between 5 to 8 letters, but not less or more.

Comment: any domain of this celebrity?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Unfortunately this puzzle seems to be too broad at first glance, since there's a lot of things that can be done with 9 letters with not much to pin the answer down. It might be helpful to provide additional hints/context to narrow the puzzle down to one answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Adele

Explanation:

> [Adele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele) is a famous singer.

Hint 1:

> Her full name is Adele Laurie Blue Adkins. So "Adele" is not her middle name nor her last name

Hint 2:

> The word "Adele" is 5 letters long:  $5<=5 <=8$

Answer (score 2):

Celebrity's name

> [Atlee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlee_(director)) is an Tamil cinema director from India.
>
>  D,X,F,**L**,H,**A**,**T**,**E**,**E**

Hint 1:

> His original name is **Arun Kumar**, in the cinema industry he used to known as "Atlee" only.

Hint 2:

> The count of characters is Five.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is the correct answer, but it satisfies the rules:

Celebrity's Name:

> [Fateh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fateh_(rapper))

Hint 1:

> He is a rapper, his full name is Fateh Singh

Hint 2:

> His name is consisted of five letters.